# How to change the path of picture into picture in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I need to show Prod_Picture into picture, not a path text. I can't set property in GridView because I bound this code to GridView and no column has been create there.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = from c in db.Products
                   join o in db.ProductCategories
                   on c.ProdC_ID equals o.ProdC_ID
                   select new
                   {
                       ProductID = c.Prod_ID,
                       ProductName = c.Prod_Name,
                       Price = c.Prod_Price,
                       Amount = c.Prod_Amount,
                       Picture = c.Prod_Picture,
                       ProductDetail = c.Prod_Detail,
                       ProductCategory = o.ProdC_Name
                   };
        GridView1.DataSource = item;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Here source code for GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Please help !!

Comment: Can you show your ASP code?

Comment: I just add source code. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the topic below:

[Displaying Images from a Database in a GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20782/Displaying-Images-from-a-Database-in-a-GridView)

Perform the following actions for the gridview:

[image]

1. Uncheck the Auto-generate field
2. Use two BoundFields for UserName and Country
3. Set the Header Text and DataField (field name in database)
4. Use ImageField for the image and set DataImageUrlField =
   ImageFieldName
5. Click OK

Comment: Hi, I'm new in coding and this one you show me is using sql. How can I apply that to linq? I can't set property in GridView as well because GridView doesn't bound with LinqDataSource but it's bound with the code above.

Comment: I see, but the databinding is the same. Try to follow the configuration for the gridview.

Comment: @user3162003 here's another link for you that should walk you through getting the images. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I just try. I can do it now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are storing image Url as Prod_Picture.
in That case

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Prod_Name" HeaderText="Prod_Name" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="Prod_Price" HeaderText="Prod_Price" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">

 <ItemTemplate>

 <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# (string) FormatImageUrl( (string) Eval("Prod_Picture")) %>' runat="server" />

</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

<FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />

<RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />

<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />

<PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />

<HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />

</asp:GridView>
```

this will work